# Graphql, way to organize entities into tree shema

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, prisma

Yo hello,

pretty new into graphQl game, but I was wondering, is there way how to organize entities into tree schema similar to how swagger doing it? Using apollo server for UI/ debbuging of my graphQl.

Somehow turn this:

[image: GraphlQl apollo server]

Into this:

[image]

Thanks for any help or suggestions...

Using it on nodejs/ typescript, grapql, graphql-modules, prisma... Dunno if it's important.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible with current graphQL schema specification.

You can try using [this instrument](https://schwer.github.io/graphql-to-openapi/) to convert grapqhQL to openApi schema, and then edit it to add grouping. It is hardly a good solution but might help, depending on your purpose.